# How to select and exclude records from the same subset in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a sample connection table `PolicyToX` with fields `Id, PolicyId, PersonId, SchoolId`. Records are always saved with one of the FKs being NULL, for example `1, 1, 5, NULL`.

I want to write a query in LINQ that, when given two parameters: `PersonId` and `SchoolId` will filter all Policies of the given School but without those that are already bound to a given Person.

So, if I have a dataset of:

```
[Id][PolicyId][PersonId][SchoolId]
 1     1         5        NULL
 2     1        NULL       1
 3     2        NULL       1
```

and pass paremeters `PersonId = 5` and `SchoolId = 1` the result should be one Policy of ID = 2.

Thanks!

Comment: "but without those that are already bound to a given Person" - can you describe this sentence more clearly?

Comment: Sure. If there is a record with a pair of keys of a given Person and a given Policy (i.e. ID=1, PolicyId=1, PersonId=2, SchooldId=NULL), then such Policy is "bound" to the person. To make it more clear, the aim of the query is to return one set from a table (all Policies with a given SchoolId) and then from that set remove another set (all Policies with a given PersonId)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming PolicyToX contains the data then is this what you're looking for?

```
        var ids = from e in PolicyToX where e.PersonId == personId select e.PolicyId;
        var result = from d in PolicyToX where d.SchoolId == schoolId && !ids.Contains(d.PolicyId) select d;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this returns the whole set.

Comment: @barjed StevieB answer is correct. These two queries would not return whole set. First query will return IDs of polices bound to person with given personID. In your example it would be policy of ID 1. Second query will return all polices for given schoolID not bound to person. In your example it would be only policy with ID 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = list.Where(x => x.SchoolId == schoolId && x.PersonId != personId);
```

Are you talking about this?

Comment: This won't work, because one of the FK fields is always NULL. Therefore your logical AND will never be fulfilled and the result will always be empty set.